# Going from one Capital to another

Tags: word, word-property

Can you go from one Capital city to another Capital city by adding a two digit number ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could plan a lovely trip from

> BERN to BER**LI**N,
>
> by adding **LI** - 51 in roman numerals!